# Modifying an objects property inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, properties

I am looking to set the

```
opponent = search_abbreviation
```

teams is an array of team objects that, before the loop, look like:

```
var team = {
          teamId: team_id,
          teamAbbreviation: abbreviation,
          gamePlayedId: game_id,
          totalPlaysFor: offensePlays,
          totalYardsFor: offenseYds,
          yardsPerPlayFor: offenseAvgYds,
          opponent: '',
          totalPlaysAgainst: 0,
          totalYardsAgainst: 0,
          yardsPerPlayAgainst: 0
        };
```

I have the following code to find the opponent by matching the gamePlayedId's to each other, then it will update the defensive(against) stats and the opponent properties. What am I doing wrong that will not allow me to modify the opponent property?

```js
var teams = [
{
          teamId: 0,
          teamAbbreviation: 'abbreviation1',
          gamePlayedId: 11,
          totalPlaysFor: 12,
          totalYardsFor: 13,
          yardsPerPlayFor: 14,
          opponent: 'op',
          totalPlaysAgainst: 0,
          totalYardsAgainst: 0,
          yardsPerPlayAgainst: 0
},
{
          teamId: 1,
          teamAbbreviation: 'abbreviation2',
          gamePlayedId: 11,
          totalPlaysFor: 12,
          totalYardsFor: 13,
          yardsPerPlayFor: 14,
          opponent: 'op2',
          totalPlaysAgainst: 0,
          totalYardsAgainst: 0,
          yardsPerPlayAgainst: 0
}];

const result = teams.forEach(({ teamAbbreviation, gamePlayedId, teamId }) => {
      var search_gamePlayedId = gamePlayedId;
      var search_teamId = teamId;
      var search_abbreviation = teamAbbreviation;
      teams.forEach(({ opponent, gamePlayedId, teamId }) => {
        if (search_gamePlayedId === gamePlayedId && search_teamId !== teamId) {
          opponent = search_abbreviation;
          // Modify more properties
        }
      });
    });
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
teams.forEach( (team1) ) => {
  teams.forEach( (team2) => {
    if (team1.gamePlayedId === team2.gamePlayedId && team1.teamId !== team2.teamId) {
      team2.opponent = team1.teamAbbreviation;
      // Modify more properties
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I did not think of this but it seems to give me exactly what I am looking for. This is now giving me benefits beyond what I posted. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

`opponent` links to a different memory space than `teams[n].opponent` in your code.

```
teams.forEach(({ opponent, gamePlayedId, teamId }, index) => {... // adding index

// then 
teams[index].opponent = 'something'
```

or

```
teams.forEach(team => {
    team.opponent = 'something'
})
```